# how to make a progress view like the one in KAYAK app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiprogressview

I wonder how to make a progress view that looks like the one in KAYAK app (it's a travel app to search for flights and hotels), screenshot:

[image]

i dig into the resources of KAYAK app on a jailbroken iPhone and found the following 3 images that construct this progress view:

progressbar-background@2x.png

[image]

progressbar-gradient@2x.png

[image]

progressbar-overlay@2x.png

[image]

giving that the progress view has a moving overlay images that moves repeatedly along with the gradient image.

any ideas or sample code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Look into - (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets. That with any of the github suggestions should be workable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've made entire working package that will mimic this progress view you have posted. However, to make it more customizable, I have not used any images, but used CoreGraphics to draw it. The package can be found at [lightdesign/LDProgressView](https://github.com/lightdesign/LDProgressView). I'll also probably make it into a [CocoaPod](http://cocoapods.org) if you know what that is.

## How To Draw A KAYAK-like Progress View

All of the inner workings of the progress view and therefore how to mimic the KAYAK progress view can be found in [this file](https://github.com/lightdesign/LDProgressView/blob/master/LDProgressView/LDProgressView.m). I've added some comments here in the code blocks for easier understanding. Here's the `drawRect` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self setAnimateIfNotSet];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self drawProgressBackground:context inRect:rect];
    if (self.progress > 0) {
        [self drawProgress:context withFrame:rect];
    }
}
```

This is pretty self-explanatory. I set the animate property if it isn't set already  and I draw the background. Then, if the progress is greater 0, I'll draw the progress within the total frame. Let's move on to the `drawProgressBackground:inRect:` method:

```
- (void)drawProgressBackground:(CGContextRef)context inRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // Draw the background with a gray color within a rounded rectangle
    UIBezierPath *roundedRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:10];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.51f green:0.51f blue:0.51f alpha:1.00f].CGColor);
    [roundedRect fill];

    // Create the inner shadow path
    UIBezierPath *roundedRectangleNegativePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(-10, -10, rect.size.width+10, rect.size.height+10)];
    [roundedRectangleNegativePath appendPath:roundedRect];
    roundedRectangleNegativePath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
    CGSize shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.5, 1);
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGFloat xOffset = shadowOffset.width + round(rect.size.width);
    CGFloat yOffset = shadowOffset.height;
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context,
            CGSizeMake(xOffset + copysign(0.1, xOffset), yOffset + copysign(0.1, yOffset)), 5, [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7].CGColor);

    // Draw the inner shadow
    [roundedRect addClip];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-round(rect.size.width), 0);
    [roundedRectangleNegativePath applyTransform:transform];
    [[UIColor grayColor] setFill];
    [roundedRectangleNegativePath fill];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Here, I create a rounded rectangle within the view with a radius of `10` (which I may later allow to be customizable) and fill it. Then the rest of the code is drawing the inner shadow, which I don't really need to go into detail about. Now, here's the code for drawing the progress in the method `drawProgress:withFrame:`:

```
- (void)drawProgress:(CGContextRef)context withFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    CGRect rectToDrawIn = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width * self.progress, frame.size.height);
    CGRect insetRect = CGRectInset(rectToDrawIn, 0.5, 0.5);

    UIBezierPath *roundedRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:insetRect cornerRadius:10];
    if ([self.flat boolValue]) {
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.color.CGColor);
        [roundedRect fill];
    } else {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        [roundedRect addClip];
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGFloat locations[] = {0.0, 1.0};
        NSArray *colors = @[(__bridge id)[self.color lighterColor].CGColor, (__bridge id)[self.color darkerColor].CGColor];
        CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) colors, locations);

        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(insetRect.size.width / 2, 0), CGPointMake(insetRect.size.width / 2, insetRect.size.height), 0);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        CGGradientRelease(gradient);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    }

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[self.color darkerColor] darkerColor].CGColor);
    [self drawStripes:context inRect:insetRect];
    [roundedRect stroke];

    [self drawRightAlignedLabelInRect:insetRect];
}
```

There are 4 primary parts to this method. First, I do the calculation of the frame that the progress will take up based on the `self.progress` property. Second, I draw either a solid color if the `flat` property is set, or I draw a calculated gradient (methods `lighterColor` and `darkerColor` are in a `UIColor` category). Third, I draw stripes and finally draw the percentage label. Let's cover those 2 methods quickly. Here's the `drawStripes:inRect:` method:

```
- (void)drawStripes:(CGContextRef)context inRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:10] addClip];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2].CGColor);
    CGFloat xStart = self.offset, height = rect.size.height, width = STRIPE_WIDTH;
    while (xStart < rect.size.width) {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, xStart, height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, xStart + width * 0.25, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, xStart + width * 0.75, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, xStart + width * 0.50, height);
        CGContextClosePath(context);
        CGContextFillPath(context);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        xStart += width;
    }
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

This is where the animation "magic" happens. Essentially I draw these stripes based off of `self.offset` which is somewhere between `-STRIPE_WIDTH` and `0` as incremented by a timer. Then, I create a simple loop so that I only create enough stripes to completely fill the progress portion of the view. I also leave 25% of the `STRIPE_WIDTH` blank so that the stripes aren't bunched up against each other. Here's the final drawing method `drawRightAlignedLabelInRect:`:

```
- (void)drawRightAlignedLabelInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", self.progress*100];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    UIColor *baseLabelColor = [self.color isLighterColor] ? [UIColor blackColor] : [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.textColor = [baseLabelColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
    [label drawTextInRect:CGRectOffset(rect, -6, 0)];
}
```

In this method I create a label with text that is convert from a float (between `0.0` and `1.0`) to a percentage (from `0%` to `100%`). I then either set the color to be dark or light depending on the darkness of the chosen progress color and draw the label in the `CGContext`.

## Customizability

There are three properties that can be set either directly on an instance of `LDProgressView` or beforehand in a `UIAppearance` method.

- Color

The color will obviously set the general look of the picker. The gradients, stripes, and/or outline colors are determined off of this. The `UIAppearance` method would be something like this:

```
 [[LDProgressView appearance] setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.87f green:0.55f blue:0.09f alpha:1.00f]];
```

- Flat

This will determine whether the background of the progress view will be a gradient or just the `color` property. This `UIAppearance` method would look something like this:

```
[[LDProgressView appearance] setFlat:@NO];
```

- Animate

Finally, this will determine whether the stripes will be animated. This `UIAppearance` method can also be generically set for all instances of `LDProgressView` and looks like this:

```
[[LDProgressView appearance] setAnimate:@YES];
```

## Conclusion

Whew! That was a long answer. I hope I didn't bore you guys too much. If you just skipped down to here, here's is the gist for drawing in code rather than with images. I think CoreGraphics is a superior way of drawing on iOS if you have the time/experience since it allows for more customization and I believe tends to be faster.

Here's a picture of the final, working product:

[image: LDProgressView]

Comment: I have downloaded your project from Github but the animation does not work at all, i've tried to hook up the progress view with an IBOutlet then kick off the animation with setAnimate but to no avail ... is there something missing with the code to work correctly ?

Comment: I've updated it… I'll specifically test an IBOutlet to see if I have a problem.

**Update:** I've tested the latest version with an IBOutlet, and it works fine. Give it a try and see if it still doesn't work.

Comment: thank you so much i has worked now, but there is a recurring error in the console that says: <Error>: clip: empty path , how can i remove this annoying error ?

Comment: Alright, I've fixed the path error. I accidentally had an extra `CGContextClip` function in my code.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but how can I use this within interface builder?  I am supporting iPad, all iPhone screen sizes, as well as rotation.. and was wondering if I can replace the UIProgressBar I currently am using in IB with this..?

Comment: You'll want to drag a UIView over to your controller and then change its class to `LDProgressView`. Finally, I would add an `IBOutlet` to your code and configure the properties there. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NSTimer` to update the "offset" at which you start rendering the overlay. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/larcus94/LBProgressBar). It's OS X control and it uses custom drawing, not images, but the principle is the same.

Comment: do you have an iOS compatible version of this project ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but take a look at [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com) I'm sure you can find something similar there.

Comment: Just found this in case you're still searching: https://github.com/lightdesign/LDProgressView

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the color and thickness and you are good to go!
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ylprogressbar

This one seems good too... but I have not use it yet.
https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGProgressView

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some of example which you can just modify some of code and getting the progress view as you want :
check [Example1](https://github.com/YannickL/YLProgressBar) and [Example2](https://github.com/larcus94/LBProgressBar)

Answer (score 1):

The Closest related Progress Bar in your case is [ADVProgressBar](https://github.com/appdesignvault/ADVProgressBar).

Here, you need to do a little bit modification. Like, you have to change the Back ground image and you can add those Rounded corners. After those changes, the progress bar will look exactly like what you mentioned in your Question.

---

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom cocoa control

[ADV control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/advprogressbar)

Comment: Is this helpful to you??

Comment: it does not satisfy the requirement in the question

Comment: Why is that doesn't meet as per your requirement?

Comment: I need the moving behavior of the progress view with the overlay frames, download Kayak app and try it out

Answer (score 0):

Try Cocoa Controls for the ProgressView....... as for the overlaying images, you need to use a NSTimer that relays in absolute sync with the progressview

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your `UIProgressView` (`self.progress`) us the following set up to get the same look:

```
        UIImage *mynd =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"KgcoJ.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(11, 13, 11, 13)];
        UIImage *bakMynd =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"UoS0A.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(11, 13, 11, 13)];
        [self.progress setProgressImage:mynd];
        [self.progress setTrackImage:bakMynd];
```

Note you may have to change the image names and the numbers in the `UIEdgeInsetsMake` depending on your image sizes.
That will give you the following:
[image: Progress bar with Images]